# Getting $2^4 = x^2+6x$ from $4 = \log_2(x^2+6x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I am having trouble with this grade 12 pre-calc question that I am sure will be elementary to most of you. I understand most of it, but I do not understand one of the steps.

These are the steps in my answer-key:
\begin{align*}
4 & = \log_2x+\log_2(x+6)\\
4 & = \log_2(x^2+6x)\\
2^4 & = x^2+6x
\end{align*}

What happens to $4$ to become $2^4$? Thanks!

Comment: Hint: how do you get rid of the $log_2$ on the RHS? Look at laws of logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that $$\log_a(b) = y \iff b = a^y$$ In your case, we have
$$\log_2(x^2+6x) = 4 \iff x^2+6x = 2^4$$